# Jquery drop down menu validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, validation

I have a simple drop down menu in html.  The html code is shown below.

```
<select id="dmm_ios">
  <option value="1.0.0">1.0.0</option>
  <option value="1.1.1">1.1.1</option>
  <option value="1.2.3">1.2.3</option>
  ....The options available go on and on..
</select>
```

I also have json code similar to the drop down menu.  My goal would be to check to see which option the user selected, and then I'd like to be able to see which json objects have similar values.

I thought I'd be comparing values so I did something like this...

```
var ios = $("#ddm_ios").val();

if ($.inArray(ios, Products.iphone4.GeveyPro.ios) === -1) {

} else {

}
```

But I'm not sure the code will work.  So I try something simple.  I tried to find the "typeof ios", and I got undefined as a result.

Comment: We have to see the JSON values too so that we can compare - can you please add them to your post?

Comment: var Products = {
  
    "iphone4" : {
 
  "GeveyPro" : {
   
   "ios" : ["4.1", "4.2", "4.2.1", "4.3", "4.3.1", "4.3.2", "4.3.3", "4.3.4", "4.3.5", "5.0.0", "5.0.1"];
   "baseband" : ["1.59", "2.10", "3.10.1", "4.10", "4.10.1"];
    },
  "GeveyUltra" : {
   "ios" :["4.1", "4.2", "4.2.1", "4.3", "4.3.1", "4.3.2", "4.3.3", "4.3.4", "4.3.5", "5.0.0", "5.0.1"];
   "baseband" : ["1.59", "2.10", "3.10.1", "4.10", "4.10.1", "4.10.01"];
    },
    
 },

Comment: Hopefully you can read that.  The ios in the json is an array which contains strings of numbers

Comment: You can simply [edit your post](http://i.imgur.com/1OU0v.png) to add the relevant info :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: `ddm_ios` in your selector should be `dmm_ios` to match the actual id of your dropdown or vice versa.

```
var ios = $("#dmm_ios").val();
```

Comment: uggg I **hate** when that happens! ;) Other than this typo looks to *me* that your code is ok...

Comment: @jap - He is talking about the spelling of your selector - `dmm_ios` or `ddm_ios` - double `d` or double `m`

Comment: @JaPerk14, yes, # selects an id. It's just that you tried to select `$("#ddm_ios")` but the id of your select element is `dmm_ios` which is not the same thing. You need to use `$("#dmm_ios")` in this case.